# List<long> testList = new List<long>(id) gives error in C#

Tags: c#

```
long id= 10;
List<long> testList = new List<long>(id);   /*creating to List of long */
```

Above statement gives error in C# and intelligence saying to convert it to int. At the same time when i do it like below it is working as expected.

```
long id= 10;
List<long> testList = new List<long>();    /*creating to List of long */
testList.Add(id);
```

what is the reason behind it?

Comment: Better to read documentation. This constructor expects List capacity value.

Comment: You just want to create a list with `id` as its single element, right? You do not want to call [this constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-collections-generic-list-1-ctor(system-int32)), right?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, thanks for the answer. I think it will help

Answer (score 1):

List initialization (probably want you want to do) is done like this in C#:

```
long id = 10;
List<long> testList = new List<long>() { id };
```

Inside the curly brackets you can put multiple elements separated by comma which the list shall initially contain.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 constructors for the List class.

```
public List()
public List(IEnumerable<T> collection)
public List(int capacity)
```

You are trying to initialize the list using the constructor that takes capacity (which should be `int`, not `long`).

`List.Add()` method adds data to the list. So, your statement of creating list object v/s adding element to list is what giving you the error.